# How to comment links on YouTube without getting deleted?

Tags: video, hyperlink, youtube, upload, comments

A few times I tried to share a link in the comments, but the comment is automatically deleted every time. Is there a trick to bypass this irritating feature?

I tried to search for a possible solution for it, but unfortunately, I did not find any solution. please help me solve this problem, if you have any suggestions don't hesitate to reply to my question. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the channel owner doesn't allow links in their comment section, then, comments with links are removed - for avoid phising/spam content.

If that's the case, you cannot post link(s) in comments.